# ActiveAdmin actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

is there a way to specify in ActiveAdmin's index page of a model what actions are allowed, things like:

```
index do
  actions :edit
end

index do
  actions only: :edit
end
```

do not work. What's the correct syntax?

Appreciated.

```
bundle show activeadmin
/home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/active_admin-9cfc45330e5a
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add whatever actions you want to be available by using `actions` (it is usually put under model definition):

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  actions :index, :show, :create, :edit, :update
  # ...
end
```

If you want to specify the method for certain action, you can do

```
action_item only: :show  do
  link_to 'Edit', action: :edit # so link will only be available on show action
end
```

Comment: Is the action `:create` or `:new`? If I use `actions :all, except: [:create]` I still get a "New" button on the edit page. Using `actions :all, except: [:new]` makes the button go away.

Answer (score 15):

Example how to play with the action column. In this example I just re-implemented the default one, but you can do powerful coding here:

```
column :actions do |item|
  links = []
  links << link_to('Show', item_path(item))
  links << link_to('Edit', edit_item_path(item))
  links << link_to('Delete', item_path(item), method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?')
  links.join(' ').html_safe
end
```

Comment: This worked for me (the selected answer didn't). Only thing is that `item_path` should be something like `admin_itemname_path` and `edit_item_path` should be `edit_admin_itemname_path`.

Comment: This is a perfect situation for .tap.  `Array.new.tap do |links| { links << link_to ... }.join(' ').html_safe`

Comment: for the confirm, it should be `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`

Answer (score 6):

Do this way,

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  actions :all, :except => [:destroy]
end
```

or

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  actions :only => :edit
end
```

Need to be specified at resource level not in method definition

Comment: Based on the [source code](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L80) it should be customized in method definition too, but only with adding new actions and disabling default actions completely.

Comment: @GaborGarami, you can customize it inside individual method. Check this out http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#custom_action_items

Comment: Andrey also showed how it can be customized, but I guess muichkine is only dealing with defaults actions.

Comment: Actually the winning answer is Gabor's one :)

Comment: I could not get :only to work...but I did find that "actions :index" got the job done. That is, it excluded :edit, :view, etc.

Answer (score 6):

According to source code, https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L80

if one want to change the actions in the index he should go with

```
actions defaults: false do |sample|
  link_to t('active_admin.edit'), admin_sample_path(sample)
end
```

where you can replace the link title and the path for the action

**For Example:**

```
    actions defaults: false do |user|
      link_to t('active_admin.view'), admin_user_path(user)
    end
```

**Note:**

Keep in mind that add the path correctly like for `show` it should be `admin_user_path(:id)` and for `index` it should be `admin_users_path` :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple custom actions, instead of dealing with joining the links manually like Ziv Barber did, you can also use the `item` method like so:

```
actions defaults: true do |user|
  item "Report", report_admin_user_path(user), method: :put
  item "Unlock", unlock_admin_user_path(user), method: :put
end
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to put a label in the table header for the column where the `View Edit Delete Report Unlock` links are shown?

Comment: To add a space between "Report" and "Unlock" add `class: "member_link"` according to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216947/inserting-a-space-after-appending-multiple-actions-in-activeadmin