# Inserting a space after appending multiple actions in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, activeadmin

I'm having an issue while trying to append multiple actions in the index page in activeadmin.

I used this code to append two actions in activeadmin.

```
actions defaults: false do |resource|
  item "View", resource_path(resource)
  unless resource.approved?
    item "Edit", edit_resource_path(resource)
  end
end
```

The problem is the links appear next to each other like this

```
ViewEdit
```

Next thing I did was add a space using text_node which resulted in this

```
actions defaults: false do |resource|
  item "View", resource_path(resource)
  text_node " "
  unless resource.approved?
    item "Edit", edit_resource_path(resource)
  end
end
```

This gave me this output:

```
View
Edit
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I get to display these two links next to each other.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the class `member_link`

```
actions defaults: false do |resource|
  item "View", resource_path(resource), class: 'member_link'
  unless resource.approved?
    item "Edit", edit_resource_path(resource), class: 'member_link'
  end
end
```