# How to show edit link only in show view using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to show the link in the show view of ActiveAdmin. But it should not show up in the grid of the index view. I can't figure out how to do this. I've already tried quite a few approaches.

#### attempt 1

```
actions :all, except: proc{ params['id'].present? ? [:new, :destroy] : [:new, :destroy, :edit] }.call
```

this fails with  `undefined local variable or method 'params'`

#### attempt 2

```
  actions :all, only: :show, except: [:new, :destroy, :edit]
  action_item only: :show do
    link_to 'Edit Cash Out', "/admin/documents/#{params['id']}/edit" if params['id']
  end
```

this fails because the route isn't being created for the edit path

#### attempt 3

```
  actions :all, except: [:new, :destroy].tap do |a|
    a << :edit unless params['id'].present?
  end
```

fails with `no block given`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you only want to hide the link to the edit action in the index page (in the grid).

If this is correct, one possible solution is included in this answer:

[possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990813/11883546)

```
index do
  column :actions do |item|
    links = []
    links << link_to('Show', show_item_path)
    links << link_to('Delete', delete_item_path, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?')
    links.join(' ').html_safe
  end
end
```

Just keep in mind to adjust the aforementioned code to fit the routes and naming.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code?

```
actions :all, only: :show, except: [:new, :destroy, :edit]

action_item :view, only: :show do
  link_to 'Edit Cash Out', "/admin/documents/#{params['id']}/edit" if params['id']
end
```

Comment: @AntarrByrd Can you please also mention which active admin version are you using?