# Rails ActiveAdmin display only view action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got standard ActiveAdmin table view for index. The thing is I want to show only `View` if it comes to `action`. Like below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Conversation do
(...)

  index do
    column 'User email', :sendable
    column :tag
    column 'Category', :topic
    column 'Last update', :updated_at
    actions only: :show
  end
end
```

`actions only: :show` is not working. Is there any way to do this without using `action_item` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727623/activeadmin-actions

Comment: @JoelBlum those answers includes `action_item` which, like I wrote, I want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
actions :all, except: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Let me know if it doesn't.